# how to save result from lookup table to case property in CommCare

Tags: commcare

I am saving the output of a single choice lookup table question as a case property.   This is not a question completed by the user, but calculates off of the user case.  
The lookup table has two columns
1. Index (sequential numbers)
2. Study condition (1,2,3,4)

In the lookup table, the filter_id is set to 'index'. 
*note: this 'index' increments based on a counter from the mobile worker (user-case).

How do I save the 'study_condition' that corresponds to that index row in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is not a question completed by the user you should just use a hidden value with a calculate condition.  The calculate would be:

```
instance('your_lookup_table_id')/your_lookup_table_id_list/your_lookup_table_id[index = #form/index]/study_condition
```

Where "lookup_table_id" = the id of your lookup table and #form/index you should just drag the index question in your form over.

Finally, be sure to include the instance statement in your form so it loads the lookup table you need. It should look like:

```
<instance id="your_lookup_table_id" src="jr://fixture/item-list:your_lookup_table_id></instance>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I had an error in my original post which I just edited.  In your example it should be:

instance('assign_condition')/assign_condition_list/assign_condition[index = #form/s3_nmsm/index]/S3_NMSM

Also note I removed the "/" from in front of your #form. But you're better off just dragging that form question into the calculate instead of typing out the #form so you know it'll be right.

Answer (score 0):

Nick, thanks for your answer. The app builds on HQ, but I am seeing a syntax error on mobile.

do you see the error in this calculate condition

instance('your_lookup_table_id')/your_lookup_table_ids[index = #form/index]/study_condition

instance('assign_condition')/assign_condition[index = /#form/s3_nmsm/index]/S3_NMSM

Comment: Please do not write anything in answer section other than answer to question.